# How to import contact via CSV and trigger CiviRule for Trigger "Address is added"

Tags: contacts, import, civirules, csv

I set up a CiviRule that when an Address is added for a Contact some relationships are created depending on the zip code for that Contact.

Now I create some Contacts via an import of a CSV file. I assign the correct rows to be mapped into the Home Address and I can see the correct data in the Contact after importing.

~Unfortunately, the Trigger "Address is added" in CiviRule is not triggered, and the rule is not executed.~

How can I make sure that the rule is triggered correctly?

I found out that the Trigger "Contact of any type is added" is in fact triggered during the import. but for that one I cannot add a "Field value filter" for a field that belongs to the address (eg. the zip code).

Any ideas on that?

UPDATE:
I tried to reproduce the behavior, and now "Address is added" was triggered. My working hypothesis is, that I imported a contact that was already there and thus (via duplicates) was only updated, but no adress really added. I close this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger is potentially not fired because the import process does not fire the corresponding **post** hook for the address. So Civirules simply does not "see" that an address is created. If that is true you could say that it is not so much a problem of Civirules but more a problem of the import, although that does not help you.

That might be the case but you could try with a "addess is changed" trigger to see if that works?

If you are familiar with debugging it is pretty straightforward to check if the Address **post** hook is fired. Are you?

Comment: no, I'm not yet familiar with debugging civiCRM